# java "execute" method to load library

Tags: java, javaagents

I'm trying to figure out how does the VirtualMachine.loadAgentPath works in a native way, Because of some difficulties I can't use the java code to perform my agent loading and have to make it with native code.

I looked into the implementations of HotSpotVirtualMachine and saw that it is calling some execute method to perform the loading

```
private void loadAgentLibrary(String agentLibrary, boolean isAbsolute, String options) 
    throws AgentLoadException, AgentInitializationException, IOException {
    InputStream in = execute("load", agentLibrary, isAbsolute ? "true" : "false", options);
    try {
        int result = readInt(in);
        if (result != 0) {
            throw new AgentInitializationException("Agent_OnAttach failed", result);
        }
    } finally {
        in.close();
    }
}
```

But I can't figure out how I can call that execute or load  method
Has anyone tried that before?

Thanks

Comment: The `execute` method is platform-dependent. Did you have a look at its code?

Comment: I couldn't find it, all I could find is the abstract form of it

Comment: Well, here's a tip: if you run into such a case in GrepCode, go to the hierarchy section. It usually shows appropriate subclasses if they exist. [Here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/sun/tools/attach/LinuxVirtualMachine.java?av=h#LinuxVirtualMachine) is a link to the Linux implementation.

Comment: I looked at the WindowsVirtualMachine.java code that implements it, and I can see that it calls some enqueue function to queue the command to the remote process. now where the hell is enqueue :S

Comment: well, found enqueue and realized that it also an exported function within attach.dll that inject code into the remote java process and do all kinds of stuff.. I really don't want to try and implement my own enqueue cuz it looks pretty damn hard and messy. any way to call it with the right arguments?